# Logistic Regression with loads of parameters

Tags: python, r, statistics, logistic-regression, glmnet

I have access to some betting data. I.e. historical betting suggestions by 30.000 different users as well as their outcome and their original odds.

Given a new bet suggestion from a user I want to predict the probability that the bet comes true. I'll start out with a very simple binomial model by

```
P(bet = success | user = u and odds = o) = exp(1/o + b_u) / (1 + exp(1/o + b_u) )
```

Hence the logit probability intercept in the probability determined by the betting site (1/odds) and have an additive effect from the user, so I end up with 30.000 parameters.

I intend to estimate the parameters using logistic regression in either python or R. Using `patsy` in python (to create the designmatrix) or `glm` in R I run into memory problems. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: How many bets per user do you observe?

Comment: It spans from 1 to 15.000

Comment: I have like 3.5 mio bets

Comment: if you really want to fit users separately, you might as well break the problem up and run it either sequentially or in parallel ...

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I understand your problem. You have a dataset with 3.5 million bets, from 30000 users. Each bet has a stated outcome (what the user bets) and an actual outcome. You want to predict whether the stated and actual outcome are the same, ie, whether the user wins.

So you have (at least) 2 predictor variables: the odds given by the betting site, and the user ID, with the latter being a factor with 30000 levels. You can formulate the data as a 3.5 million x 3 data frame: `win`, `odds` and `user`. Then fit an elastic net model with [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmnet), because you have ~30k regression coefficients and some form of regularisation is probably not a bad idea.

The first problem is that creating the model matrix to fit the model will chew up tons of memory. Luckily, glmnet gives you the option of using a *sparse* model matrix, so that only a large-but-still-reasonable amount of memory is required.

The second problem is that at least in R, even if you have enough memory, creating the model matrix will probably take more time than fitting the model itself.

You can use the [glmnetUtils](https://github.com/hong-revo/glmnetUtils) package to get around these issues. glmnetUtils is a shell for glmnet to make modelling easier; it supports a formula interface, and also streamlines the handling of wide datasets like this one. In particular, it gets around the limitations in R's built-in model matrix functionality noted above.

Sample code:

```
library(glmnetUtils)

# build an example data frame
# response is win
# predictors are real_logodds (ie, as offered by betting company) and user ID
set.seed(34567)
df <- local({
    nbets <- 3.5e6
    nusers <- 30000
    user <- sample(nusers, size=nbets, replace=TRUE)
    real_logodds <- rlogis(nbets)
    b_user <- rnorm(nusers, sd=0.1)
    user_logodds <- b_user[user] + real_logodds
    outcome <- rbinom(nbets, size=1, prob=plogis(real_logodds))
    bet <- rbinom(nbets, size=1, prob=plogis(user_logodds))
    win <- outcome == bet
    data.frame(win, outcome, bet, user=factor(user), real_logodds)
})

system.time(mod <- glmnet(win ~ real_logodds + user, data=df, family="binomial",
                          sparse=TRUE))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  30.77    1.19   30.94 

mod
# Call:
# glmnet.formula(formula = win ~ real_logodds + user, data = df, 
#     family = "binomial", sparse = TRUE)
#
# Model fitting options:
#     Sparse model matrix: TRUE
#     Use model.frame: FALSE
#     Alpha: 1
#     Lambda summary:
#       Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
# 2.032e-05 5.528e-05 1.503e-04 2.792e-04 4.086e-04 1.110e-03 


system.time(cvmod <- cv.glmnet(win ~ real_logodds + user, data=df, family="binomial",
                               sparse=TRUE))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  373.60   26.82  388.58 

cvmod
# Call:
# cv.glmnet.formula(formula = win ~ real_logodds + user, data = df, 
#     family = "binomial", sparse = TRUE)
#
# Model fitting options:
#     Sparse model matrix: TRUE
#     Use model.frame: FALSE
#     Number of crossvalidation folds: 10
#     Alpha: 1
#     Deviance-minimizing lambda: 0.0007649709  (+1 SE): 0.001109842
```

Here, I generate a sample data frame with the dimensions given in the question. Then I fit a regularised logistic regression, which takes ~30 seconds. I also do 10-fold crossvalidation to choose the elastic net shrinkage parameter, which takes about 6 minutes.

Disclosure: I'm the author of glmnetUtils.